# importing spring jars in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jar

I am importing spring jars in a dynamic web project in eclipse. I have downloaded the jars added to class path but I am getting :

```
The import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView cannot be resolved
```

`ModelAndView.class` is present in package `org.springframework.web.servlet`

Packages are resolved in java file but not the classes :

[image]

Under servlet package there are some java classes but they are not visible from java file only packages are visible.

If i try this on other jar it shows java classes and packages :

[image]

Comment: Have you added them to lib folder of your project?

Comment: They were in WEB-INF, i am able to import java classes after under WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: You should really use Maven or Gradle. You can even use [Initializr](https://start.spring.io) to set everything up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure this jar - spring-webmvc.jar is your your classpath